# Find matches between an Array and an Objects' array

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, object, match

I have a blog with some articles. 
Every USER has a prop named "favorites" which is an array of favorite posts. When a user clicks on the "heart icon" placed in every post, the name of the post will be added to the user prop.

I would like to create a section on the profile page where the user can see which posts they added to favorites. To do this I've to match the ARRAY of the USER to the ARRAY of the POSTS.

```
    userFavoritesArray = ['post1', 'post2', 'post5', ...]
    postsArray = [
      { title: 'post1', 
        desc: 'hello'
      },
      ...
    ]
```

EXAMPLE:

```
user: {
favorites: ['post1']
}

posts: [
{name: 'post1', desc: 'yo bro'},
{name: 'post2', desc: 'hello im the post2'},
{name: 'post3', desc: 'good morning'}
]
```

The output I wish to have for this user would be `favorites: [{name: 'post1', desc: 'yo bro'}]`

Comment: can you give an example of the output you're after?

Comment: please add the wanted result. and your try.

Comment: @NinaScholz I edit the topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not entirely clear, but I'm guessing what you want is this:

```js
const input = ['a', 'c']
const database = [
  { title: 'a', foo: 1 },
  { title: 'b', foo: 2 },
  { title: 'c', foo: 3 }
]
const output = mapByTitle(database, input)
console.log(output)
// Result: [ { title: 'a', foo: 1 }, { title: 'c', foo: 3 }]
```

In this case, you can use a combination of `Array.prototype.find` (which will go through an array until it finds an element for which your callback returns `true` and then return that element) and `Array.prototype.map` (which will go through an array and return a new array with all elements mapped to the return values of your callback for each element).

For example:

```js
// Usage of `find`:
console.log(database.find(item => item.title === 'a'))
// Result: { title: 'a', foo: 1 }
console.log(database.find(item => item.title === 'z'))
// Result: undefined

// Usage of `map`:
console.log(['hello', 'world'].map(item => item.toUpperCase() + '!'))
// Result: ['HELLO!', 'WORLD!']
```

So, then we can build the aforementioned `mapByTitle` function like this:

```js
function mapByTitle (database, input) {
  return input.map(title => database.find(item => item.title === title))
}
```

Comment: Hi, yeah you got me. thank you so much!
I edited the topic by the way.